# Setting tooltip on each selectItem in selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Is it possible to set up the tooltip on each individual selectItem. But it is set on the whole object  level.

Mojarra 2.2.8 version

```
<h:selectOneRadio
        value="#{managedBean.ipAddressAllocationStrategy}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1"
            itemLabel="One" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2"
            itemLabel="Two">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                title="Tooltip for two"></span>
        </f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Is there any better workaround for this

Comment: Must it really be a whole non-standard `<span>` element as expected by the 3rd party library like that instead of simply the `title` attribute on the desired `<option>` element as usual, which that 3rd party library could progressively enhance?

Comment: @BalusC. Do you mean putting the title attribute on the f:selectItem instead.

Comment: I was talking about the required HTML output. Once we know that, then it's just a matter of (re)writing JSF code in such way that it produces exactly the  desired HTML output. You're namely using a `<span>` element to represent a tooltip in a non-standard HTML way. The standard HTML way is using the `title` attribute. That non-standard way must instead be a progressive enhancement over `title` attribute by whatever 3rd party library you're apparently using for fancy tooltips.